# (Random Selection) Names From A File

Tags: java, random

I am trying to make a *random name generator* **method** that will create a random first and last name from a list of names I have stored in two separate text files. 
(First Name.txt && LastName.txt)

So essentially I want to select a random token from the text file and match it from a random token from the last name text file:

I'm just not sure how I can manipulate the string names into a respective random integer.

```
private static void selectName(Scanner firstName, Scanner lastName) {
        // Initialization of Variables
    String randomFirstName = null;
    Random rand = new Random();
    int randomName = rand.nextInt(199) + 1; // 1 - 200

    while (firstName.hasNext()) {
        randomFirstName = firstName.next();
    }

} // closes FileInformation
```

The other idea I could think of was to store the contents into an array and transverse that way?

Would that be the best way or is there a way to do it as I have now?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Of course there are many ways to accomplish the task, I think, hands down, the best way is to load all the names into an array or list, and then just index into that list based on a random number.

```java
List<String> firstnames = new ArrayList<String>();
List<String lastnames = new ArrayList<String>();
//TODO: populate your lists from the appropriate files
Random rand = new Random();
//The advantage to using a list is that you can choose a random based on the actual
//count of names and avoid any out of bounds conditions.
int firstIndex = rand.nextInt(firstnames.size());
int lastIndex = rand.nextInt(lastnames.size());
//Then you index into the list
String randomfirst = firstnames.get(firstIndex);
String randomlast = lastnames.get(lastIndex);
```